# How to create JSON object in Python

Tags: json, python-2.7

Hi I need to create a JSON object in the following format. How to go about it

```
{"user2_proximity": 3, "Wifi_1": -80, "Wifi_2": -40, "Wifi_3": -40, 
"thermostat": 18, "light": 0, "hour_of_day": 0, "user3_proximity": 3, 
"user1_proximity": 1, "day_of_week": 1, "security": 0, "minute_of_hour": 9, 
"Act_1": 1, "Act_2": 0, "Act_3": 0}
```

Comment: I'm confused... is that already JSON or a python `dict`? Those things look very similar. JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation which is a way to serialize data to exchange among systems. There isn't such a thing as a "JSON object" but there are objects in programming languages like python and javascript that can be built from them. Is this a sting and you want a `dict` or is this a `dict` and you want a string?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

source : https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

```
import json
data = {"user2_proximity": 3, "Wifi_1": -80, "Wifi_2": -40, "Wifi_3": -40, 
"thermostat": 18, "light": 0, "hour_of_day": 0, "user3_proximity": 3, 
"user1_proximity": 1, "day_of_week": 1, "security": 0, "minute_of_hour": 9, 
"Act_1": 1, "Act_2": 0, "Act_3": 0}

json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: The value of all the key i.e, user2_proximity, wifi_1 etc will be changing. Only thermostat and light value are constant.

Comment: @Anagha Update your question to be more specific, then.  Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Anagha you can change the value by data['wifi_1'] = 2, then convert it into json again

Comment: This won't retain its order by the way, if you care about that.

Comment: @GrantFoster is there way to retain the order?

Comment: I haven't tried myself but I've read to use OrderedDict. Regular dictionaries in Python don't retain order.

Answer (score 2):

`response` is a 2d array with values for keys/columns ("test_id","querytext","metrics").

`[0]['testid1','query1','"metrics": { "ndcg@3": "1.0", "ndcg@7": "0.9" }']
 [1]['testid2','query2','"metrics": { "ndcg@3": "1.0", "ndcg@7": "0.9" }']`

```
column_names=("test_id","querytext","metrics")
    json_response={}
    for entry in response:
        if entry[0] not in json_response:
            json_response[entry[0]]=[]
        json_element={}
        json_element[column_names[1]]=entry[1]
        json_element[column_names[2]]=json.loads(entry[2])
        json_response[entry[0]].append(json_element)
    return json.dumps(json_response)
```

Now `json_response` will be of following format

`{
    "tesid1": [{
        "querytext": "query1",
        "metrics": {
            "ndcg@3": "1.0",
            "ndcg@7": "0.9"
        }
    }],
    "testid2": [{
        "querytext": "query2",
        "metrics": {
            "ndcg@3": "1.0",
            "ndcg@7": "0.9"
        }
    }]
}`