# How to convert SQLAlchemy data into JSON format?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working on SQLAlchemy and want to fetch the data from database and convert the same into JSON format.

I have below code :

```
db_string = "postgres://user:pwd@10.**.**.***:####/demo_db"
Base = declarative_base()
db = create_engine(db_string)  

record = db.execute("SELECT name, columndata, gridname, ownerid, issystem, ispublic, isactive FROM col.layout WHERE (ispublic=1 AND isactive=1) OR                                            (isactive=1 AND ispublic=1 AND ownerid=ownerid);")

for row in record:
    result.append(row)

print(result)
```

Data is coming in this format:

```
[('layout-1', {'theme': 'blue', 'sorting': 'price_down', 'filtering': ['Sub Strategye', 'PM Strategy']}, 'RealTimeGrid', 1, 0, 1, 1), ('layout-2', {'theme': 'orange', 'sorting': 'price_up', 'filtering': ['FX Rate', 'Start Price']}, 'RealBalancing Grid', 2, 0, 1, 1), ('layout-3', {'theme': 'red', 'sorting': 'mv_price', 'filtering': ['Sub Strategye', 'PM Strategy']}, 'RT', 3, 0, 1, 1)]
```

But I am facing a lot of issues to convert the above result into JSON Format. Please suggest.

Comment: Without giving details on your issues it is not possible for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is basically a list of tuples.

like first tuple is like

```
('layout-3',
 {'filtering': ['Sub Strategye', 'PM Strategy'],
  'sorting': 'mv_price',
  'theme': 'red'},
 'RT',
 3,
 0,
 1,
 1)
```

if you want to convert whole data as it is to json, you can use `json` module `dumps` function

```
import json
jsn_data = json.dumps(data)
```

Your list of tuple is converted to json

```
[["layout-1", {"theme": "blue", "sorting": "price_down", "filtering": ["Sub Strategye", "PM Strategy"]}, "RealTimeGrid", 1, 0, 1, 1], ["layout-2", {"theme": "orange", "sorting": "price_up", "filtering": ["FX Rate", "Start Price"]}, "RealBalancing Grid", 2, 0, 1, 1], ["layout-3", {"theme": "red", "sorting": "mv_price", "filtering": ["Sub Strategye", "PM Strategy"]}, "RT", 3, 0, 1, 1]]
```

but If you need json formate as key value pair , first need to convert the result in python dictionary then use `json.dumps(dictionary_Var)`

Comment: How can I convert the result into dictionary ?

Comment: creating a dictionary, 
Python dictionary is like `hashmap` or `key->value pair`, So you have to add the key corresponding to each value based on your data requirements.
You can loop over your data and create a dictionary.
```dct = dict()
dct['Name'] = 'My_name'
dct['phone_num'] = [908934335,9867347343],
dct['id'] = 'My_id'```
then you can json dump the `dct`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542734/how-to-create-json-object-in-python/41542859

Answer (score -1):

What you want to accomplish is called "serialization".

You can follow Sudhanshu Patel's answer if you just want to dump json into response.

However if you intend to produce a more sophisticated application, consider using a serialization library. You'll be able to input data from request into db, check if input data is in the right format, and send response in a standarised format.

Check these libraries:

- [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/index.html)
- Python's own [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Please check code snippets on the Marshmallow website, it has a great documentation and it will clarify this concept much better.